# How to make multiple aggregate function without break / divided the fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to make an aggregate function without break / divided the grouping fields? I make a query but it will divided into duplicate value in the first field, here is my query:

```
SELECT      TOP 5 empname AS 'EMP Name',    
            SUM (CASE WHEN prod = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Count of Prod',
            COUNT (prod) AS 'Total Account',
            FORMAT (COALESCE (SUM (CASE WHEN prod = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT (prod), 0), 'P') AS '% Prod',
            DATEDIFF(DAY, t_start, t_end) as 'Duration Trip'
FROM        Sampletable
WHERE       empname NOT IN ('NA') AND 
            empname IS NOT NULL AND
            t_end IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY    empname, 
            prod,
            t_end,
            t_start
ORDER BY    [Count of Prod] DESC
```

My expected result:

| Emp. Name | Count of Prod | Total Account | % Prod | Duration Trip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Emp.1 | 62 | 63 | 98,41% | 30 |
| Emp.2 | 45 | 48 | 93,75% | 28 |
| Emp.3 | 20 | 22 | 90,91% | 25 |
| Emp.4 | 20 | 24 | 83,33% | 22 |
| Emp.5 | 15 | 19 | 78,95% | 20 |

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us your sample data and your actual results.

Comment: And don't add tag names to the title... tagging them is enough.

Comment: @Harle users are *not* going to trust some file from a stranger on the internet; many of us are professions and are all to aware how *foolish and dangerous* it is to download and open a file from an unknown person. Put the DDL and DML in your question.

Comment: Sorry i am newbie here, i will put it in DDL and DML

Comment: Sorry, i didn't know how to input my data into there, can you suggest me more where can i input my sample data and also my query result?

Comment: *"can you suggest me more where can i input my sample data and also my query result"* in the question.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one row per `empname`, then that should be the only column in the `group by` (or perhaps other columns that describe each employee without multiplying the number of rows).

That suggests something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 empname,    
       SUM(CASE WHEN prod = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS prod_count,
       COUNT prod) AS Total_Account,
       FORMAT(AVG(CASE WHEN prod = 'P' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END), '%P') AS prod_ratio,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, t_start, t_end)) as trip_duration
FROM Sampletable
WHERE empname NOT IN ('NA') AND 
      empname IS NOT NULL AND
      t_end IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY empname
ORDER BY prod_count DESC;
```

Note some of the changes to the query:

- The column aliases are simplified so no escape characters are needed.
- The `GROUP BY` has only `empname`.
- The logic for the proportion of products is simplified using `AVG()`.
- I assume that the trip duration should be a sum of the individual durations.
- I did not remove it, but `empname IS NOT NULL` is redundant, because the `NOT IN` handles this.